# Searching a 2D sorted matrix part, need a code review if i did it on O(n)

Tags: java, algorithm, performance

we have got a task:

"Write an efficient algorithm that searches for a value in an n x n table (two-dimensional array). This table is sorted along the rows and columns — that is,
Table[i][j] ≤ Table[i][j + 1], 
Table[i][j] ≤ Table[i + 1][j]"

if someone can review my code and see if I am at O(n), or I can make my code more efficient.
thanks.

```
public static boolean find(int [][]a, int x)  // Efficiency O(n)
{

    if(a.length == 0 || a.length != a[0].length) // check if the matrix is squared or empty
        return false;


    int row = 0, col = a.length-1; // setting coordinates

    while(row < a.length && col >= 0) // running while the coordinates in bounce 
    {
        if (x > a[row][col])    // the "x" is bigger then my current spot, go down 1 row
            row++;
        else if(x < a[row][col])    // // the "x" is smaller then my current spot, go back 1 col
            col--;
        else
            return true;    
    }
    return false;
```

Comment: Just adding some rough idea as to binary search on first column, get the row which could have it and then binary search on that row to find out. So time complexity would be O(log(cols)) + O(log(rows)) or you can say, O(max(log(cols),log(rows)).

Comment: Well, for code reviews there's... ehm... codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my rough sketch but it improves your search. I tried binary search from 2D array. Hope it helps

```
static int moves = 0;

public static boolean find1(int[][] a, int x) // Efficiency O(n)
{

    if (a.length == 0 || a.length != a[0].length) // check if the matrix is squared or empty
        return false;

    int row = 0, col = a.length - 1; // setting coordinates

    while (row < a.length && col >= 0) // running while the coordinates in bounce
    {
        moves++;
        if (x > a[row][col]) // the "x" is bigger then my current spot, go down 1 row
            row++;
        else if (x < a[row][col]) // // the "x" is smaller then my current spot, go back 1 col
            col--;
        else
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean find(int[][] a, int x) // Efficiency O(n)
{

    int row = findRow(a, x);
    print(row);
    if (row < 0)
        return false;
    int col = findCol(a[row], x);
    print(col);
    if (col < 0)
        return false;
    return true;
}

public static int findRow(int[][] a, int x) {
    int row = a.length;
    int start = 0, end = a.length - 1;
    while (start <= end) {
        moves++;
        int current = start + (end - start) / 2;
        if (a[current][0] <= x && a[current][a[current].length - 1] >= x) {
            return current;
        } else if (a[current][a[current].length - 1] < x) {
            start = current + 1;
        } else {
            end = current - 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

public static int findCol(int[] a, int x) {
    int start = 0, end = a.length - 1;
    while (start <= end) {
        moves++;
        int current = start + (end - start) / 2;
        if (a[current] == x)
            return current;
        if (a[current] < x)
            start = current + 1;
        else
            end = current - 1;
    }
    return -1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int[][] a = { { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }, { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 }, { 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 },
            { 21, 22, 23, 24, 25 } };
    print(find(a, 21));
    print(moves);
    moves = 0;
    print(find1(a, 21));
    print(moves);
}
```

print function is just System.out.println(), i am just lazy ;)

Comment: Did you copy the code from somewhere? That `moves++` doesn't look like it belongs there

Comment: i did not copy it, i just tried to see how many moves it takes to find, you can remove it if you want. Also you can improve findCol function if you only want boolean value